# How do I extend a type declaration from DefinitelyTyped in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

As a concrete example of this, I am trying to change the type of `Express.Response.locals` from `any` to an app-specific `AppLocals` interface. I am using `@types/express`.

I tried a few things none of which seems to work:

```
declare namespace express {
    export interface Response {
        locals: AppLocals
    }
}
```

Gives the error: `Import declaration conflicts with local declaration of 'express'` Coming from `import * as express from 'express'` at the head of the file.

If I try to replicate the structure found [in the source](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts#L14):

```
declare global {
    namespace Express {
        export interface Response {
            locals: AppLocals
        }
    }
}
```

Then the locals property of `express.Response` in a handler still is of type `any`.

If I try this, just for the heck of it:

```
declare namespace Express {
    interface Response {
        locals: AppLocals
    }
}
```

TypeScript tells me that `'Express' is declared but never used`

Comment: You can't change a type of an existing property. You can add more properties, but the ones that are already set are not changeable.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
declare module "express" {
  interface Response {
    locals: AppLocals
  }
}
```

In my case, the only thing I wonder is if I can have multiple of these and have TS merge the type of `locals`, I haven’t been able to do that yet, so I just extend my other route specific locals from `AppLocals` and cast the response.